# A Recycler View or Card View with Swipe Gesture's which slides in a carousel whenever a task is assigned [Android Studio - Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture, materialcardview

I have roughly sketched a design in which under the mainActivity there should be a carousel/card view (With Recycler Spanning) portraying the task details assigned to the user and it should be enabled with swiping gesture where the user would swipe for determining the state of the tasks such as Pending, In Progress, Completed also the card should change its color (Orange, Yellow, Green respectively) whenever the appropriate swipe is done and it should get into the queue of carousel.

[image: UI - iam working on currently]

Below the Roamie's Dashboard the card should be implemented.

[image: UI - Thats required to be created]

Comment: Please can you elaborate

Comment: I have a more or less unique design pattern for a card view which allows the user to swipe with gestures in order to change the state of the task assigned to them. But i am not sure which design pattern, functionalities i should be using to achieve this

Comment: can show me some ui prototype such that I could understand